# Track shifting and zooming object between frames

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tracking

I'm trying to track cars using video from dash cam. Most of the time there is

1. slight shifting of a vehicle in front of me
2. on/off brake lights
3. zoom in when it uses brakes
4. Zoom out when it accelerates.

What algorithm will be the best for this case? Of course, I can just run open cv, but I want to understand how it works. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your task you can use the Haar Cascade Classifier. It is a machine learning based approach where a cascade function is trained from a lot of positive and negative images. It is then used to detect objects in other images.

There is a good openCV's implementation, with both the trainer and the detector.
On the web you can even find a lot of .xml files, that are the result of the training part, and use these .xml files to do directly the detection.
Even if i'm not really sure that you can find these files for the detection of the back of a car.

At this link you can learn the bases of the method and you can even understand how to use it in openCV http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

In this case you don't need the 4 features that you suggested, but maybe you can use that with another algotrithm at the end of the pipeline of the Haar Cascade Classifier for a double check.